# store JSON response in array angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I know this question is not really good to ask. But can any one help me out. here

I have a response getting from the server and i want to store that in an array .

```
$scope.getAllDatesAvailable=[];
    $http({ 
      method:'GET',
      url:"",
      params:{
        code:"76357" 
      }
    }).then(function success(response){
      if(response.data.result==1){
       console.log(response.data.vote_time_slots);          
        $scope.getAllDatesAvailable=response.data.slot;
```

When I write `console.log($scope.getAllDatesAvailable)` it is saying `undefined`.

I also want it to be stored on a local storage so later I can traverse through each object in this array and do other operations.

Can anyone help me in these two cases?

Comment: Create plnkr or Fiddle.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a simple "store array in localstorage" (or a similar query) would give you 2-3 results on google about this extremely rare, almost never seen before, requirement

Comment: We have no idea what your data structure looks like to know why you are getting undefined

Comment: @AlonEitan not unusual to store whole array in one localStorage key

Comment: @charlietfl Well OK, 10 results then

Answer (score -1):

```
.then(function success(response){
   $scope.getAllDatesAvailable = response;
)}
```

and if you want to store your array in local storage:

```
localStorage.ArrayName = JSON.stringify($scope.getAllDatesAvailable);
```

Comment: This provides no explanation how it solves OP's problem. In addition, it  assigns wrong object